# Optimize hyperparameters hidden_layer_size MLPClassifier with skopt

Tags: python, scikit-learn, skopt

How can I optimize the number of layers and hidden layer size in a neural network using `MLPClassifier`  from sklearn and `skopt`?

Usually I'd specify my space something like:

```
Space([Integer(name = 'alpha_2', low = 1, high = 2),
       Real(10**-5, 10**0, "log-uniform", name='alpha_2')])
```

( let's say hyperparameters `alpha_1` and `alpha_2`).

With the neural network implementation in sklearn I need to tune `hidden_layer_sizes` which is a tuple:

```
 hidden_layer_sizes : tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default=(100,)
     The ith element represents the number of neurons in the ith
     hidden layer.
```

How can I represent this in `Space`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `gp_minimize` you can include the number of hidden layers and the neurons per layer as parameters in `Space`. Inside the definition of the objective function you can manually create the hyperparameter `hidden_layer_sizes`.

This is an example from the [scikit-optimize homepage](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/hyperparameter-optimization.html), now using an `MLPRegressor`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from skopt.space import Real, Integer, Categorical 
from skopt.utils import use_named_args
from skopt import gp_minimize

boston = load_boston()
X, y = boston.data, boston.target
n_features = X.shape[1]

reg = MLPRegressor(random_state=0)

space=[
    Categorical(['tanh','relu'],name='activation'),
    Integer(1,4,name='n_hidden_layer'),
    Integer(200,2000,name='n_neurons_per_layer')]

@use_named_args(space)

def objective(**params):
    n_neurons=params['n_neurons_per_layer']
    n_layers=params['n_hidden_layer']

    # create the hidden layers as a tuple with length n_layers and n_neurons per layer
    params['hidden_layer_sizes']=(n_neurons,)*n_layers

    # the parameters are deleted to avoid an error from the MLPRegressor
    params.pop('n_neurons_per_layer')
    params.pop('n_hidden_layer')

    reg.set_params(**params)

    return -np.mean(cross_val_score(reg, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1,
                                    scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error"))

res_gp = gp_minimize(objective, space, n_calls=50, random_state=0)
```